# ios 8 interactive notifications not showing actions

Tags: ios, ios8, notifications, interactive

This is my code to register Interactive Notifications for ios8 :

```
+ (void)registerInteractiveNotifications
{
    UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *corideInviteCategory = [self corideInviteCategory];
    UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *riderInviteCategory = [self riderInviteCategory];

    NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObjects:corideInviteCategory, riderInviteCategory, nil];
    UIUserNotificationType types = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|
                                    UIUserNotificationTypeSound|
                                    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);

    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings;
    settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types
                                                 categories:categories];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
}

+ (UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *)riderInviteCategory
{
    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *accept;
    accept = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    [accept setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground];
    [accept setTitle:@"Accept"];
    [accept setIdentifier:RiderInviteAccept];
    [accept setDestructive:NO];
    [accept setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *decline;
    decline = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    [decline setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground];
    [decline setTitle:@"Decline"];
    [decline setIdentifier:RiderInviteDecline];
    [decline setDestructive:YES];
    [decline setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

    UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *actionCategory;
    actionCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
    [actionCategory setIdentifier:RiderInviteCategory];
    [actionCategory setActions:@[decline, accept]
                    forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];
    [actionCategory setActions:@[decline, accept] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextMinimal];

    return actionCategory;
}

+ (UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *)corideInviteCategory
{
    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *accept;
    accept = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    [accept setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground];
    [accept setTitle:@"Accept"];
    [accept setIdentifier:CorideInviteAccept];
    [accept setDestructive:NO];
    [accept setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *decline;
    decline = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    [decline setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground];
    [decline setTitle:@"Decline"];
    [decline setIdentifier:CorideInviteDecline];
    [decline setDestructive:YES];
    [decline setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

    UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *actionCategory;
    actionCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
    [actionCategory setIdentifier:CorideInviteCategory];
    [actionCategory setActions:@[decline, accept]
                    forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];
    [actionCategory setActions:@[decline, accept] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextMinimal];

    return actionCategory;
}
```

What happens is : when i delete the app and install again, the 2 action buttons (when I pull down the notification banner, or swipe left in notification center) appears. But after a while ( i'm not really sure what cause it ), they stop appearing although i keep sending the same notification. This is my notification content:

```
{"aps":{"alert":"test","category":"coride_invite"},"journey_id":100}
```

Can anyone shed some light please ? Thanks

Comment: Have you solved this yet?

Comment: I am facing same issue although our server and APNS show same category Key that we assigned but still no Buttons shown up

Answer (score 1):

Check for the following in you code if it is anywhere else as well:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
```

Since, `UIUserNotificationSettings` is singleton, whenever you call this, it overwrites the old settings. So if new settings is registered without any buttons it will not show any buttons.

Better way of registering new setting is explained here:
[Interactive push notifications - Hide/Show buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37982802/interactive-push-notifications-hide-show-buttons/37983764#37983764)